# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a un control creado dinámicamente en un datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagrid

Necesitaba crear una columna de `CheckBox` en un `DataGridView` y en la cabecera de esta un `CheckBox`de seleccionar todos.
Lo hice en forma de métodos en una clase estática a los que le paso el `DataGridView` y me lo montan.
Los metodos en cuestion son:

```
//Añade la columna de checkboxs en la primera posicion.
public static void AddCheckColumn(DataGridView dgv)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    chkCol.Name = "colCheck";
    chkCol.HeaderText = "";
    chkCol.Width = 30;
    chkCol.ReadOnly = false;
    dgv.Columns.Insert(0,chkCol);
}
//Crea un objeto CheckBox, lo asocia a la colección de controles del DataGridView y lo mueve al lugar del header.
public static void CheckHeader(DataGridView dgv, EventHandler HeaderCheck_Clicked)
{
    CheckBox chkHead = new CheckBox();
    Point headerCellLocation = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;
    int cellWidth = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1,true).Width;
    int cellHeight = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Height;
    chkHead.Location = new Point(headerCellLocation.X + 8, headerCellLocation.Y + 2);
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.White;
    chkHead.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    chkHead.Size = new Size(18, 18);
    chkHead.Click += HeaderCheck_Clicked;
    dgv.Controls.Add(chkHead);
}
```

Para controlar la propiedad checked del CheckBox creado dinamicamente en el header, accedo a su propiedad desde el sender del evento:

```
    private void frmOfertes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
        string queryCmbFam = "SELECT codigo,nombre from " + DB.SQLDatabase("GESTION", "familias");
        cmbSubfam.Enabled = false;
        funcions.EmplenaCombo(queryCmbFam, cmbFam);
        funcions.AddCheckColumn(ewgrid1);
        funcions.FiltreGridArticles(cmbFam, cmbSubfam, ewgrid1);
        funcions.CheckHeader(ewgrid1, HeaderCheck_Clicked);
        Dictionary<string, int> ampleCamps = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"codigo",80 },
            {"nombre",200 }
        };
        funcions.ColumnSize(ampleCamps, ewgrid1); 
    }

    private  void HeaderCheck_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkHead = (CheckBox)sender;
        ewgrid1.EndEdit();
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in ewgrid1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chkbox = (row.Cells["colCheck"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell);
            chkbox.Value = chkHead.Checked;
        }
    }
```

Lo que hago en este evento, es igualar los `CheckBox` de la columna del `DataGridView` al estado del `CheckBox` del `header`.

Ahora necesito hacerlo a la inversa, es decir, si selecciono todos los registro mediante el `checkBox` del `header`, necesito que al deseleccionar uno de ellos, se deseleccione también el `checkBox` del `header`.
Pero no sé cómo acceder a este control.

```
private void ewgrid1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RowIndex >=0 && e.ColumnIndex ==0)
    {
        bool isChecked = true;
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in ewgrid1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["colCheck"].EditedFormattedValue) == false)
            {
                isChecked = false;
                break;  
            }
        }
    }
    chkHead.Checked = isChecked;---> ¿Cómo accedo a chkHead ?
}
```

**EDIT**:
Por si a alguien le ayuda, he conseguido acceder al `checkbox` de la cabecera mediante la colección de controles del `dataGridView`, aunque debo decir que a pesar de que el control del `checkbox` del `header` es correcto, el comportamiento del la función que uso para activar o desactivarlo según el estado de los `checkboxs` de la columna no es el esperado, pero ese ya es otro tema.

```
private void ewgrid1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkHead = (CheckBox)ewgrid1.Controls["chkHead"];

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        //Loop to verify whether all row CheckBoxes are checked or not.
        bool isChecked = true;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ewgrid1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["colCheck"].EditedFormattedValue) == false)
            {
                isChecked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        chkHead.Checked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Buena pregunta, he usado mucho el control `DataGridView` y no se me había ocurrido esa solución, es genial, siempre aprendemos contestando las preguntas. Dejé una respuesta, pues al problema de hacer referencia a controles creados dinámicamente si me he enfrentado muchas veces, es el aporte de mi modesta experiencia, te recomiendo que pruebes la solución que te brindo y si la encuentras útil te agradecería que la puntearas y la marcaras como aceptada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Eduardo, finalmente lo he hecho accediendo al control mediante su colección de controles.
Edito mi pregunta para adjuntar el código.

Comment: Esa es una solución muy elegante, pero es valida para un solo control con nombre "chkHead", si solo se agrega una columna con esas características, tanto la columna como el `CheckBox`, pueden ser variables declaradas de antemano, aunque se creen y se agreguen de manera dinámica; pero si en tu aplicación se pudieran agregar  más de una columna de este tipo, para hacer referencia al `CheckBox` asociado a una columna determinada, siempre habría que implementar una forma de asociar el control con su columna, ya sea almacenando una referencia al propio control o a su nombre.

Comment: Tomo nota, un placer Eduardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución es almacenar una referencia al `CheckBox`en una variable que puedas recuperar adecuadamente, para esto lo mas apropiado es la propiedad `Tag` de la propia columna `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, para ello en el evento `CheckHeader` en ves de pasar como argumento el `DataGridView`yo pasaría como argumento la columna asociada, así como aparece a continuación.

```
   //Crea un objeto CheckBox, lo asocia a la colección de controles del DataGridView y lo mueve al lugar del header.
public static void CheckHeader(DataGridViewColumn col_dgv, EventHandler HeaderCheck_Clicked)
{
    CheckBox chkHead = new CheckBox();
    chkHead.Bounds = col_dgv.HeaderCell.ContentBounds;
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.White;
    chkHead.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    chkHead.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    chkHead.Size = new Size(18, 18);
    chkHead.Click += HeaderCheck_Clicked;
    col_dgv.DataGridView.Controls.Add(chkHead);
    //Agregas una referencia al control chkHead en la propiedad Tag de la columna asociada
    col_dgv.Tag = chkHead;
}
```

En el evento `ewgrid1_CellClick`, lo que tendrías que hacer es recuperar el control `CheckBox` asociado desde la propiedad `Tag` de la columna, siempre haciendo la debida conversión, pues la propiedad `Tag` es de tipo `object`.

```
private void ewgrid1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool isChecked = true;
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ewgrid1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["colCheck"].EditedFormattedValue) == false)
            {
                isChecked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //Recuperamos el control CheckBox, desde la referencia almacenada en la propiedad Tag de la columna.
    CheckBox chkHead = (CheckBox)ewgrid1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Tag;
    chkHead.Checked = isChecked;
}
```

Espero que la respuesta te resulte satisfactoria, pruebala y mucha suerte.